# Weird mouse behavior in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse

I am a newbie in Ubuntu and want to understand/prevent a mouse behavior in applications (text and code editors). This behavior includes:

1. Select each and every line my mouse is hovering over.
2. Scroll up or down as my mouse exits the text region upwards or downwards.
3. Clicks stop being captured in applications. I can click on the Ubuntu menu bar. But within applications I can only move the mouse around, but unable to click.

Every time this happens I have to restart my computer, and I have even lost unsaved documents due to this.

[image]